# Symfony2 building ManyToOne relationship in Entities

Tags: symfony, oracle11g, entity

I have two entities in a OneToMany relationship, Perfil and IPerfil. Perfil can have several IPerfil's associated:

`>`

```
    class Perfil  
    {  
    /**  
     * @var integer $id  
     *  
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_perfiles", type="integer")  
     * @ORM\Id  
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")  
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="P360.perfiles_seq")  
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IPerfil", mappedBy="id")  
*/  
    private $id;
```

And the other one:

`>`

```
class IPerfil  
{  
    /**  
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Perfil")  
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_perfiles", referencedColumnName="id_perfiles", onDelete="CASCADE")  
*/  
    protected $id;
```

I'm able to lazyload from IPerfil to Perfil, but not in the other direction (from Perfil to IPerfil), but if I can't do any DQL over IPerfil or createQueryBuilder()->setPameter... Symfony will always return an error like this:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'id_perfiles FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

If I define the field Id with an

> `@ORM\Column(name="id_perfiles", type="integer")`
>   Then I'm able to build DQL's with the entity, but the relationship won't work anymore.

I'm lost around here... It seems I'm missing something in the relationship definition, but have no clue.

Thanks in advance for any tip.

### EDIT

### If I use:

```
$entities=$em->getRepository('usuariosBundle:IPerfil')->findAll(array());
```

It doen'st gives an error, but I need to filter and order the results.

---

```
$entities=$em->getRepository('usuariosBundle:IPerfil')->findBy(array(),array('id' => 'asc', 'descripcion' => 'asc'));
```

**Unrecognized field: id**

---

```
$query=$em->getRepository('usuariosBundle:IPerfil')->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();       
        $entities = $query->getResult();
```

**[Semantical Error] line 0, col 60 near 'id ASC': Error: 'id' is not defined. **

---

```
$entities = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT p.id FROM usuariosBundle:IPerfil p ')->getResult();
```

*[Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'id FROM usuariosBundle:IPerfil': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.*

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is useful to anyone, I finally created a non-persistent attribute in the Perfil entity to attach the the relationship and a collection of IPerfil's there:

```
/** 
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IPerfil", mappedBy="id") 
*/ 
private $desc;
```

Need to declare it as a ArrayCollection:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->desc = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

And now I'm able to lazy load in the right direction and do any necessary operation. I suppouse Doctrine couldnt load the collection into id, as it wasn't declared as a collection and it's the ID field.

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute name of class, no column name on dql => 'id'

`->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC')` and `->createQuery('SELECT p FROM usuariosBundle:IPerfil p ')->getResult()`, the name of bundle is usuarios os Usuarios ?

Comment: Of course I did, I use DQL's in other Controllers and it goes fine. Just won't work here. 
I'm on Oracle 11, forgot to mention, not sure if does matter.

Comment: Just Edited the Question with info about the errors I'm getting.

Comment: ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC') and ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM usuariosBundle:IPerfil p ')->getResult(), the name of bundle is usuarios os Usuarios ?

Comment: Hello @Ciro Vargas, maybe I'm missing something, but I think you didn't see that I updated the question. I already tried both ways you propose. 
The bundle's name is 'usuarios'. 
I'm not really seeing the point in this error. Btw, why isn't necessary @ORM\Column when you spicify a Relationship?

Comment: Ah sorry, I've seen the difference that you use in the ->OrderBy() 'p.id' instead of 'p', and that works! Thanks for the help. But I'm still unable to filter or groupby, it is still giving the same errors as I described in the question. 
However I'm not seeing a real difference with the methods I tried, don't really know why they won't work. I'm starting to be really lost around here. 
Thanks again.

Comment: If it is useful to anyone, I finally created a non-persistent attribute in the Perfil entity to attach a collection of IPerfil's there: 
`code`
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IPerfil", mappedBy="id")
     */
 private $descripcion; `code`

Comment: If it is useful to anyone, I finally created a non-persistent attribute in the Perfil entity to attach a collection of IPerfil's there: 
`/**`
`* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IPerfil", mappedBy="id")`
`*/`
`private $descripcion;`

And now I'm able to lazy load in the right direction and do any necessary operation.